# I am trying to use spring security 3.1.3 in my jsf 2 application but i get the following exception

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

Stack trace

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:587)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
        at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        ... 21 more
```

This is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">


  <!-- Location of the XML file that defines the root application context
    applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- this is security configuration file which maps urls according to user 
        roles authorization -->
    <beans:import resource="classpath:/com/mycompany/myproject/service-beans.xml"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsf*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page='/login.jsf' default-target-url="/default.jsf"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myDetailsService" class="com.mycompany.myproject.security.MyDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="loginService" ref="com.mycompany.myproject.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

> I checked the dependencies and i found that spring-aop 3.0.7 & spring-asm 3.0.7 are downloaded by maven while i am not including them in pom.xml dependencies & each time i remove them from the .m2 repository maven download them again, the following is the pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyProject Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring-version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-330 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>

<!--        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> -->
    </build>
</project>
```

While i am checking the maven dependency tree i found that spring-security-core, & spring-security-web downloads the spring aop,asm v3.0.7 will that be a problem?

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] com.clinicia.myclinic:MyClinic:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:runtime
```

I am new to spring security, i appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a JSF problem, you're wiring a bean wrongly (as indicated by your stack trace.)

Comment: Yes, i tried to remove the spring security configuration and it worked fine, & i traced the bean wiring and i can't find the problem

Comment: Seems to be a version mismatch issue. I had faced a similar issue where i had mixed spring 3.0.x with 3.1. if you have used maven then check the maven dependency tree to find the mismatches or check the web-inf/lib etc where u have may placed the jars. Spring-expression.*.*.jar may be the culprit . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchFieldError` almost always indicates version incompatibility.

Make sure that you don't have different versions of Spring libraries in your classpath.
If you use Maven, run `mvn dependency:tree` and check its output for possible incompatibilities.

Comment: I checked the versions and all of them using spring version 3.1.3 & i ran the command that you mentioned and there was no version incompatibility